# Convergence of integrals given pointwise convergence and some other conditions but not $L^1$ dominance.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose

1. $f_n, f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ are bounded, uniformly continuous, and go to zero at infinity.
2. $|f_n| \leq |f|$
3. $f_n \to f$ pointwise
4. $0 \leq \int f_n \leq 1$
5. $\int f_n$ converges
6. $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$

Can we conclude $\int f_n \to \int f$?

Note that $\int |f| < \infty$ is **not** assumed, so it is not obvious if Fatou or dominated convergence can be applied here.

Comment: Hint: $f_n(x) = \sin(x) / n $ for $|x|\le n\pi$ and $0$ else.

Comment: @user251257 Does 6. hold? Correct me if I am wrong, but $f_n \to f=0$, $\int |f|=0$, and $\int |f_n| = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x = 2$. I guess also 2. does not hold.

Comment: my mistake $f_n(x) = \sin(x) / k$ for $(k-1)\pi \le |x| \le k\pi$ and $k=1,\dotsc,n$, and $f_n(x) =0$ otherwise.

Comment: @user251257 So $f_n(x) \to f(x) = \sin(x)/ \lceil |x| / \pi \rceil $? Here $\lceil y\rceil$ denotes the least integer exceeding the real number $y$. And what happens with the integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x) }{k}, & (k-1)\pi \le |x| \le k\pi, k=1,\dotsc, n, \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
It is easily to see that:

1. $f_n$ has compact support, and admits the Lipschitz constant $1$.
2. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, defined by
   $$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(x) }{k} $$
   for $(k-1)\pi \le |x| \le k\pi, k\in\mathbb N$.
   In particular, $f(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to 0$ and also admits the Lipschitz constant $1$.
3. $|f_n|$ increases to $|f|$.
4. $\int f_n = 0$ and thus converges
5. $\int |f_n| = 4 \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1} \to \infty = \int |f|$.
6. As $\int |f| = \infty$, $\int f$ isn't well-defined.

N.B. There is a result stating: If $f_n$ and $f$ are **integrable** and $f_n\to f$ a.e. Then, $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ if and only if $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you learn to construct counterexamples like this? Is there a specific book or sequence of problems that you feel helped you develop this?

Comment: @LucasSilva uh. You just try. You can make an easier counter example without uniform convergence. That was just my first idea.